# Do the processes in main memory have a process control block ?Or a PCB for a process is formed when it enters the ready queue

Tags: operating-system, system

Do the processes in main memory have a process control block ?Or a PCB for a process is formed when it enters the ready queue.
Long-term schedular bring the process from  memory(hard disk) or main memory(ram) to the ready queue?

Comment: Feel free for any queries.

Comment: Under what operating system? Under what configuration? What does "formed" mean?

Answer (score 0):

Every process (i.e., everything with a process id) has a PCB, and the PCB is required to insert the process in the ready queue.

A long term scheduler decides which submitted jobs become processes, and turns jobs into processes.  Part of turning a job into a process will involve creating the PCB.

Comment: So the jobs list reside in which memory ram or hard disk. .....Are u trying to say that long term scheduler select a job from job queue to be a process and add it to ready queue.  Then I would like to aaj where the job queue resides?

Comment: Long Term Scheduler selects the jobs from the job pool which reside in secondary memory and puts those processes in the ready queue in the main memory. Now the answer to your question about PCB. OS creates the PCB as soon as the process comes into the existence.